# MVC, jquery, hoverIntent, Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, hover, hoverintent

I am having one heck of a time with hoverIntent.  I keep getting "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method" popping up.  If I change .hoverIntent to .hover, it "works".  I've tried the regular file and the minified file and neither work.  I downloaded them from [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

I only have 2 scripts on the page.  (this is in the MVC masterpage that I am trying to do this)

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mailImage").hoverIntent(showMailHover, hideMailHover);
        });

            function showMailHover() {
                alert('Hover');
            }

            function hideMailHover() {
                alert('Leave');
            }

</script>
```

here's what my navigation item looks like that I'm trying to attach this this to.

```
<ul>
   <li id="mailImage">
    <img style="padding-top: 10px;" align="left" height="24" width="24" src="/content/images/icons/envelope.png" />
   </li>

...
</ul>
```

Ideally, I'm trying to create a drop down navigation.  But, I can't get hoverIntent to work on my most basic tests in order to move forward with it.  Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: Talked to one of hte other devs, they tried using jqModal on the same masterpage the other day and had the same exact error/problem.  The masterpage isn't anything special, so it doesn't make any sense why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax checks out - I just downloaded the plugin and created a quick local test with your script and HTML - so the problem is with your JS file reference(s). I recommend using FireBug's 'Script' tab to ensure both scripts are being references and loaded correctly.

Comment: I use IE, and looking at the developer tools (they have something similar to firebug), it appears to be loaded.  There are two references to the script under Jscript - windows script block

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery's .hover() function on that page?

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct, which would lead me to guess that there is a typo in your `jquery.hoverIntent.js` spelling or location...

Comment: I thought that too and I did a direct copy-paste of the file name. No luck. The path is correct. It's in the same folder as the jquery file.

Answer (score 1):

What if you add the ul prefix?

Ie:

```
<ul id="ulID">
  <li id="mailimage" ...
```

then

```
$("#ulID li").hoverintent(...
```

Comment: Man, now I'm very curious myself!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried another masterpage and it worked fine.  So I dug around and found out a slider control we were using had a reference in the control to the jquery file.  That meant the page had 2 references to the same js file.  I removed the second reference and all is well.

Thanks to all who offered their help.

Comment: Good to know Josh, seems like that kind of stuff is a daily occurrence for me. :)